Modified Joule-Thomson expansion
I was trying to solve a thermodynamics problem about the Joule-Thomson (Joule-Kelvin) expansion and I can't reach the answer. The book has the solution, but there's a term which I don't get where it comes from. I tried the first law of thermodynamics but I couldn't arrive to the same result. The term I don't understand is $c_{v}\mathrm{d}N(\tau' - \tau)$, I believe this term comes from $\mathrm{d}U = C_{v} \mathrm{d}T$ and that they are using something like $C_{V} = c_{v} \mathrm{d}N$, but I don't understand why they're assuming constat temperatures, because temperature is changing in B. The images are attached at the end.
The problem is from the book A Guide to Physics Problems (Cahn, Mahan, Nadgorny).



I suppose it's a approximation instead of an exact solution. If you think about it the energy of a gas $dN$ that enters $B$ changes its temperature assuming the gas already in $B$ is a heat bath $\tau '$, i.e. the gas already in $B$ doesn't get or lose energy from heat of the entering gas. I don't know how to add this interchange of heat.

Please don't use images for text and equation. Rather, type the relevant passage and use MathJax for math symbols and equations.
